# Site error: the ionCube PHP Loader needs to be installed

Tags: php, apache, ioncube

I use ubuntu 19 as my os  and I use apache2 
I have a WordPress site that shows me this error

> Site error: the ionCube PHP Loader needs to be installed.

and  I installed ioncube and I do restart apache 
, in php info :

```
php -i |grep "with the ionCube PHP Loader"
```

the results is

> with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.3.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by ionCube Ltd.

Comment: Well that's the phpinfo for CLI. Check that your website is using the same PHP version, that it's the same with respect to thread safety (most likely both are non-TS), and that the same primary php.ini file is used. If all is good and the Loader shows in the website phpinfo yet there is still the error, there's a mistake in whatever code is reporting the error. If the Loader isn't showing in phpinfo but environment is the same as for CLI, check logs.